# I'm tring to code to get a popup marker on my leaflet map when I double click on the map

Tags: leaflet, popup, google-maps-markers, double-click

I want to get a popup marker(by image) on my map every time I double click on the screen. Every time I try to copy other's code, it won't work. Can someone help plz?THE MARKER NEEDS TO BE AN IMAGE!

I try to copy other's code, but it won't work. I'm still new in this line of work, so I don't know really how to do it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    layers: [
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ],
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});

map.on('dblclick',(e)=>{
    L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup('Hello World').openPopup()
})
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/u7QL15wYzLprVwhP

Custom icons: https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-green.png',
    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], 
});

L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: It needs to be an image marker. Like a orange marker etc.